# Oriented Object question on object's context

Tags: php, oop

If I have a class like this:

```
class1{
  public function doSomething($value, class2 $object){
    $object->setAVariable($value);
  }
}

class2{
  protected $AVariable;

  public setAVariable($value){
    $this->AVariable = $value;
    return $this->AVariable;
  }

  public getAVariable(){
    return $this->AVariable;
  }
}
```

in test.php:

```
$object2 = new class2();
$object1 = new class1();
$value = 12;
$object1->doSomething(12, $object2);
```

---

Question:

Still in test.php, can I access $value like this:

```
echo $object2->getAVariable();
```

which would return 12?

Comment: Seems to be a TIY question: *try it yourself*. Did you run the code? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix doSomething method in class1 to:

```
  public function doSomething($value, class2 $object){
    $object->setAVariable($value);
  }
```

And it will be ok. Your example, however, doesn't work, but I assume it is typing mistake.

Comment: Yes that was typing. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `$object1` in `class1:doSomething()` is undefined. If you use `$object` there instead, it will work, because `doSomething()` will call `$object->setAVariable()`, what is in this case the same object, like `$object2` fromt the outer scope (you gave that object to `doSomethig()`).